# Why is :notice not showing after redirect in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in my controller

```
  def create
    @tv_show = TvShow.new(params[:tv_show])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tv_show.save
        format.html { redirect_to(tv_shows_path, :notice => 'Tv show was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @tv_show, :status => :created, :location => @tv_show }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @tv_show.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the following  in my tv_shows/index.html.erb

```
<div id="notice"><%= notice %></div>
```

but when I create a new entry the notice message does not appear after the redirect to tv_shows_path. Have anyone an idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the code didn't work was a problem with my authentication code... After I implemented my new way of authentication from scratch the code above is working.

Comment: I wonder if you might be specific.  I'm having the exact same problem, and this answer does not help.  My controller has `before_filter :authenticate_user!`.  Is that wrong?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know anymore what the problem was a year ago. At the moment I use has_secure_password since Rails 3.1 and this works really great for me.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

Answer (score 18):

Is there any reason you're trying to use `:notice` and not `flash[:notice]`?

Controller:

```
 respond_to do |format|
  if @tv_show.save
    format.html { 
      flash[:notice] = 'Tv show was successfully created.'
      redirect_to tv_shows_path 
    }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @tv_show, :status => :created, :location => @tv_show }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @tv_show.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <div id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think Shaun is right about the View, it should be "flash[:notice]".

Comment: I read that this would be the new way with rails version 3... But I will try your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: The code was correct but I had a authentication problem and because of this the code wasn't working...

Comment: `:notice` and `:alert` are accepted in `redirect_to` in Rails 3.

Comment: The OP is asking about rails 3, which allows us to use the old flash has keys as options passed to render/redirect.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered similar 'problem' and the cause was that I was redirecting to action that in itself had another redirection. In the above case the most probable cause was that within `tv_shows_path` another redirection exists.

In my case I had something like this in a filter:

```
redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Unauthorized access!'
```

And `root_url` was set to point to `home#index`:

```
# Home controller
def index
  if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin?
    redirect_to users_path
  else
    redirect_to customers_path
  end
end
```

This second redirect_to was causing my 'unauthorized_access' notice not to show up.

The solution is to simply redirect to `customers_path` immediately and not to `root_url`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do a `flash.keep` where the second redirect happens (before the `redirect_to` call). This is what I did and it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and the error was so silly but sometimes unnotable.

I have in my application layout the following code:

```
<div id="content" >
    <div class="wrapper">
        <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
            <% content_tag :div, msg, class: "flash #{name}"%>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, can you see why I was unable to see my flash message?

Yup! You should check if you put the  `=` sign here:

```
<%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "flash #{name}"%>
```

Comment: In the `content_tag`, it should be `msg` instead of `:msg`