# flash notice is lost on redirect, how to find out what's removing it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There are many posts on SO about this ( [respond_with redirect with notice flash message not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101631/respond-with-redirect-with-notice-flash-message-not-working)  [Why is :notice not showing after redirect in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799395/why-is-notice-not-showing-after-redirect-in-rails-3), among others) , I've read at least 4 and still can't solve this issue.

I've got a portion of my site that lets people do some things before they create an account. I prefer this from a UX perspective. So they're allowed to do X and Y then they get redirected to the "Create account" page (uses Devise).

The redirect looks like:

```
if userIsNew 
  ... stow information in a cookie to be retrieved later ...     
  redirect_to "/flash", flash[:notice]  
    => "Ok, we'll get right on that after you sign up (we need your email)." 
      and return # this has to be here, since I'm terminating the action early
end
```

So `"/flash"` is a plain page that I made to test this. It doesn't do anything, has no markup of its own, just has the basic html from the application.html, which has this line in the body:

```
 <% if flash[:notice] %>
    <p><%= notice %></p>
 <% else %>
  No notice!
 <% end %>
```

It says 'No notice' every time.

I have tried:

- adding in a flash.keep to my `before_filter` in the static controller
- using `:notice =>` instead of `flash[:notice] =>`
- putting the notice in a cookie and pulling that text out of the cookie and into a flash in the before_filter of my application controller
- `redirect_to :back` with the `flash[:notice] =>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's either

```
flash[:notice] = 'blablabla'
redirect_to foo_url
```

or

`redirect_to foo_url, notice: 'blablabla'`

Comment: But I've seen a ton of sample code out there that is `flash[:notice] =>`

Comment: flash is some kind of an hash. You need to assign 'blablabla' to notice, right? To assign a value to a hash you do: hash[:key] = value. hash[:key] => value doesn't make sense to me. Since Rails 3, you can do redirect_to foo_url, :notice => 'blablabla' (or notice: 'blablabla' with the newest ruby syntax). You may mix up those two

Comment: jcollum: That "ton of sample code" is wrong. It's never, ever been `flash[:notice] =>`. If you can find an example it woudl help.

Comment: @RyanBigg yeah it looks like I was reading a sample that was using parens (odd in the Ruby world) and I was missing that there was a close paren on one line with a flash on the next. But I have seen a lot of sample code out there with `:notice =>`

Comment: Also, I see now where I got the flash[:notice] => from -- my brain was munging up the ":flash => { :info => "Message" }" with the flash[:notice] = "Message".

Answer (score 7):

I'm overriding `ApplicationController#redirect_to` to call `flash.keep` so that any messages are persisted on redirect without having to explicitly call `flash.keep` in my controller actions. Works well so far. Haven't had a scenario yet where unwanted messages are persisted.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def redirect_to(*args)
    flash.keep
    super
  end
end
```

Let me know if there are any scenarios where this isn't a good solution.

Comment: I wish Rails would only remove messages if they have been displayed/accessed

Answer (score 6):

I have been fighting with the same problem for some time and none of the posts seemed to help.
It turns out that - like usually it happens - the the problem was in my code. I did have a "redirect_to" that I forgot about, which was clearing the flash.

Namely, "root_path" for me was served by the StaticPagesController's home method. "home" was doing some checks and then redirecting you to the user_path.

In my code I had in numerous places

```
 redirect_to root_path, :flash => {error: @error}
```

These redirects were never displaying the flash because my hidden "home" controller serving the "root_path" was making another redirect that cleared the flash.

Therefore my problem was solved when i added the "flash.keep" in my "home" controller method

```
  def home
    if current_user 
        @user = current_user
      flash.keep      
      redirect_to @user unless @user.no_role?
    end 
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem, flash just disappeared after any redirect, nothing helped, then, I found that it was switched off...

Check your /config/application.rb for this:

```
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::Flash
```