# CanCan: Exception message not displaying upon redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am trying to have CanCan display an exception message when I redirect to the right page. I am handling my exceptions as per the following `application_controller` code:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  if current_user # probably not an admin
    redirect_to dashboard_index_path, :notice => exception.message
  else
    redirect_to hello_login_path, :notice=> exception.message
  end
end
```

However when I log out as a user (which triggers the else portion of the above page) and then try to access a page I should not have privilege to access it simply redirects me to the hello_login_path without displaying the exception message. *Par exemple*, when I try to go to the `dashboard#index` which has the following permissions:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #we want to list out all the the projects

    @projects = Project.all
    authorize! :read, @projects, :message => 'You are not logged in'


    @entries = Entry.all
    authorize! :read, @entries, :message => 'You are not logged in'

    @users = User.all
    authorize! :read, @users, :message => 'You are not logged in'
    #@entries = Entry.where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
    #authorize! :read, @entries

  end
end
```

It effectively redirects me to the `hello#login` page but does not display the 'You are not logged in' message.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the exception is triggered? Might it be that the redirection is done before even entering in the "index" action, maybe from a "before_filter" requiring a user to be logged in?

Comment: @taglia I believe that is probably exactly what is happening. Is there away I can avoid that behavior so that the exception is actually triggered? I have devise installed so I think it currently has the behavior you describe.

Comment: @thaglia. That doesn't seem to be the issue as I commented out `before_filter :authenticate_user!` line in the Users_controller and I still did not get the exception

Answer (score 1):

@steakchaser has the answer that solved this issue for me. If it solved your issue as well, you should accept his answer. Adding `flash.keep` to the controller action that is hit when you redirect to the `root_path` will preserve the original flash message. So, if your home controller's `index` method is hit, you'd add:

`def index
  flash.keep
  other index action code
end`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and it ended being because my root_path / url was going to another controller that was then doing another redirect.  If you've got the same sort of setup, you will want to add a `flash.keep` in your intermediate controller before it does the 2nd redirect.

I referenced this issue when researching: [flash notice is lost on redirect, how to find out what's removing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332572/flash-notice-is-lost-on-redirect-how-to-find-out-whats-removing-it)